# Scala: can't get the Future result

Tags: scala, future

I'm trying to run a simple Future example in Intellij Idea:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
object Futures1 extends App {
        val f = Future {
                Thread.sleep(500)
                1 + 1
               }
        f map println
        Thread.sleep(5)
}
```

And it is not completed.
As I suppose, due to race between main and threads in threadPool.

I tried to treat it, by:

1. Applying Await:

   ```
   Await.result(f map println, Duration(5, SECONDS))
   ```
2. Customizing execution context for switching off daemon threads:

   ```
   class MyExecutionContext extends ExecutionContext {
             override def execute(runnable:Runnable) = {
                val t = new Thread(runnable)
                t.setDaemon(false)
                t.start()
               }
             override def reportFailure(t:Throwable) = t.printStackTrace
    }

    implicit lazy val context: ExecutionContext = new MyExecutionContext
   ```

But nothing helped.

What other ways could there be?

Comment: #1 should work. Not sure what you mean by "nothing helped". Also note that your `sleep(5)` sleeps 5 milliseconds,not 5 seconds. If you change it to `sleep(5000)`, you should see the result of the printout with the original code too.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `f map println` produces a new Future?

if you say `println(Await.result(f, Duration(5, SECONDS)))`

your code works and prints out 2.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val f = Future {
    println("running future")
    1 + 1
}

println("maybe runs ahead or behind the future...")

println(Await.result(f, Duration(5, SECONDS)))

println("app finished")
```